Add Index based on two column - Power Query
I need to create an index based on two columns.
Currently my strategy is as follows but it does not work:

Use "Group By" function selecting the two desire columns, Account & Quantity
Add an index column
Expand the table with the remaining columns.



Please prove the M Code from the Advanced Editor for your current dataset.

you can try this
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Index",each List.Count(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type",(x)=>x[Quantity]>[Quantity] and x[Account]=[Account])[Quantity])+1)


